# The difference between calling this.function() and function() in Angular Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, mocha.js, factory

I have my Angular Factory this way:

```
angular
    .module('app.myModule')
    .factory('myFactory', myFactory);

myFactory.$inject = [];

function myFactory() {

    var factory = {
        func1: func1,
        func2: func2
    };

    return factory;

    //////////

    function func1() {
        if (/* some condition */) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    function func2() {
        if (func1()) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    };

};
```

`func2()` will do something depending on the result of calling `func1`, but `func1()` is not a private function because it's interesting for me to have it exposed.

Everything was fine, until I started to code this factory's unit tests. When testing `func2()`, I want to stub `func1()` just to return `true`/`false` whenever I want.

So far I coded a test:

```
describe('Test func2 if func1 returns false', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        // func1 stub setup
        sinon.stub(myFactory, 'func1');
        myFactory.func1.returns(false);

        // HERE myFactory.func1() RETURNS 'false'
    });

    it('should do something else', function (done) {
        // HERE func1() CALLED INSIDE myFactory.func2() IS NOT THE STUB

        myFactory.func2(); 

        // Do some assertions, etc.
    });

});
```

but I noticed that if I did a small change in myFactory's `func2()` code by calling `this.func1()` instead of `func1()` like this:

```
function func2() {
    if (this.func1()) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
};
```

from that point on, the stubbed `func1()` function always gets called in the tests.

At this point I'm just confused. Does anyone know what might be going on here? Would it be more "correct" to call any other public method/function inside my angular factories with `this.` if it belongs to the same factory?

**UPDATE**

`this.func1()` or `factory.func1()` work both.

Comment: This is more general then AngularJS question. Please watch this couple videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoYCgNOIyGABI011EYc-avPOsk1YsMUe_

Answer (score 0):

JS OOP best practices suggest that `factory.func1` is preferable when `func1` is supposed to be called as a callback with non-lexical `this`. Otherwise `this.func1` may be used.

In the context of unit testing `this.func1` is the best option, because it is not hard-coded to specific function or object.

In the context of testing an Angular factory service `this.func1` and `factory.func1` are roughly equivalent.